# Access denied to Google Drive when trying to create a directory from a Windows service

Tags: c#, service, google-drive-api

I'm writing a Windows service that's creating text files in a given path. Everything works just fine except when the path is a folder in my Google Drive. If the path is in Google Drive the following `Access Denied` exception is thrown:

```
exception = System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\snakile\Google Drive\folder\' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
```

The exception is thrown when reaching the following line of code:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\snakile\Google Drive\folder");
```

The problem occurs only when the folder is in Google Drive and when the `CreateDirectory` method is called from a service. In other words, when trying to `Directory.CreateDirectory(...)` to Google Drive from a simple console application it works. It fails only in the case of a windows service writing to Google Drive.

Comment: You are running the service with the same user right, you haven't created a service user? Just verifying the obvious :)

Comment: @tiki: I'm running the service as an admin.

Comment: Ah ok. I can't take this from the top of the head right now, but on some OS'es even admins don't have access to some user directories? Check the access of the folder. I don't use google drive, but remember that the rights are recursivly inherited too. Try logging in with the admin user. Just more obvious stuff ;)

Comment: I believe you have to be running "as administrator", (i.e. requested elevate privileges for the app) to access files in "other" users' directories.

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? Can we see the  code? are you using Google .net client lib? I am asking because that doesn't look anything like the code for creating a directory on Google Drive.